# SEO разные get параметры

Tags: seo

Подскажите, как индексировать страницы с разными *get параметрами* в поисковиках?
http://example.com/user.php?id={**ID**}

Придется все страницы которые есть добавлять в sitemap?

Answer (score 0):

Да лучше всего добавляй все в сайтмап.

Comment: А если их тысячи?

Comment: так воспользуйся генератором, тут все зависит от того насколько они тебе важны